# Azure - Backup scripts for custom API

Tags: javascript, azure, backup, command-line-interface, azure-mobile-services

I found [this article about using CLI for backuping scripts](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Getting_started_with_the_CLI_and_backing_up_your_scripts_Day_4_.aspx) and it's great for editing too. But I can't download scripts for Custom API. Is there a way how can I do this? I was looking in help for commands but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLI support for custom APIs should be coming shortly. Meanwhile, a great option for downloading scripts is actually enabling source control on the mobile service. That will give you a Git repository on the server which contains all your scripts (API, table, scheduler) and you can clone locally. See http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/store-scripts-in-source-control/ for more information on this feature.

**Update**: the latest version of the CLI supports custom APIs now. You can create, list, update permissions and remove APIs with the `azure mobile api` command. And you can upload / download scripts with the `azure mobile script` command.